# How to use ARRAYFORMULA to work with an array of array

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm currently working on a formula but I can't seem to make it work the way I intend to.

The column A of the spreadsheet look like something like that:

```
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |
```

And what I am trying to do is get an output like that:

```
| A |
| A | B |
| A | B | C |
| A | B | C | D |
| A | B | C | D | E |
```

So I tried using offset, to get from the first line to the current line for each of my lines.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(A1;0;0;ROW(A1:A5)))
```

But since `ROW(A1:A5)` doesn't return an array the cell was just `| A |`
So I tried adding `ARRAYFORMULA` around the `ROW(A1:A5)` and what I go was:

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
```

Which is what I need! But if I add it to the original function, I still only get `| A |`

Is there a way for me to "force" `ARRAYFORMULA` to run on `A1:A5` so that I get the required output?

**Additionnal data**

- I know this would be easier to do with a script but a script solution is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to understand why it does that and how to prevent it.
- This formula is meant to be used inside another so I need it to be only 1 formula, I can't use the cross to expand it.
- I don't mind if the solution isn't showable (if the array superpose itself by example).
- I made a demo [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dUfFGcOIIwgENpKFjvjE8djT6hG2-j8P-Mdaig6xAcQ/edit?usp=sharing).
- I also tried with `INDIRECT` instead of `OFFSET` to get the ranges and I had the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Please try, somewhere in the Row1, assuming that is where your first `A` is, and copied down to suit:

```
=SPLIT(JOIN("|",A$1:A1),"|")
```

(as an array formula, if you must.)

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A2:A6)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A6));TRANSPOSE(A2:A6);))
```

ROW() is used to create series of vertical numbers,which are compared against the same series of numbers horizontally to create a 5x5 matrix of TRUE/FALSE,which can then easily be extrapolated to the desired output.

Comment: This is interesting but in the end I can't use the result in another formula, it is interpreted as an array, not as a matrix...

Comment: A matrix is an array of array, which is what I need. I can't work with your formula because it returns a simple array so I can't use it under another array formula. It is precised in the question that I'm looking for something that I can use inside another formula.

Comment: Well if I'm trying to get the amount of `B` for each array, instead of returning `0 1 1 1 1` it returns 4, even if I use array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is located at `A1:A8` enter this formula at `C1` then copy it to `C2:C8`:

`= TRANSPOSE ( ARRAY_CONSTRAIN( $A$1:$A$8 ,
 1 + ROW() - ROW( $C$1 ) , 1 + COLUMN() - COLUMN( $C$1 ) ))`

[image]